# Do the _WRITE_BIT destination access masks imply _READ_BIT access scope?

Tags: vulkan

I think the question is clear, but in case the answer is no I'll describe the conundrum I have:

Minimal setup so a single render pass with a single subpass. Two attachments: color and depth, rendering a cube. The Depth attachment layouts (initial, mid, final) are:

- `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED`
- `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL`
- `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL`

So there's one automatic layout transition. I know that because of my `.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR`, I'll get a write-after-write warning If I don't make it visible. So I'll use this subpass dependency:

```
constexpr VkSubpassDependency in_dependency{
    .srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL,
    .dstSubpass = 0,
    .srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT,
    .dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_EARLY_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT,
    .srcAccessMask = 0,
    .dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT
};
```

This targets the early fragment test because that's where the depth att gets clear-loaded. But: Don't I also need to include the `_READ_BIT` in my `.dstAccessMask`? Sync validation doesn't seem to care, but I think I do unless I missed some rule about the write visibility implying a read visibility?

In case there is such a thing, a pointer to the spec would be nice.

Comment: `.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR` is `VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT` as [specified](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VkAttachmentLoadOp), so that case is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WRITE` does not include `READ`. This is simply a matter of the operation in question.

Clearing an image [uses the `WRITE` access mode](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-khr-extensions/html/chap9.html#VkAttachmentLoadOp). It does not use the `READ` access mode. So there's is no further hazard as far as clearing is concerned.

Once the image is cleared, the subpass can begin executing. Since subpass execution happens-after the clearing operation, there's no need for any further dependency.

Comment: Wait but isn't the depth buffer used (=read) to draw stuff? That would need a read flag, right?

Comment: @Basti: The last paragraph covers that.